# if 10% of the population are left handed, is the probability of $n$ ppl being left handed $0.1^n$? (arent these dependent events?)

Tags: probability

Problem: "According to some source, 10% of the population is left handed. How many people do you have to randomly select so that the probability of atleast one of them being left handed is 0.8?"

The negation is "all are right handed" and the solution may be $0.9^n=0.2$ (just solve this equation), but can we do $0.9^n$? If we pick a person and they are right handed, then there is one less person that is right handed, so in the next selection the chance for a right hand is smaller? So these events are dependent?

If we cannot do $0.9^n$, then I think the solution will be a lot harder to find, for example I tried something like $\frac{\binom{90}{x}}{\binom{100}{x}}=0.2$, idk if that makes any sense.

Does the fact that we are not given a specific size for the population affect this problem? For example if the size was something like 52 (deck of cards), the events would clearly be dependent, but if we are considering the entire population of the earth, then maybe the change is so small that we can ignore it?

Comment: For problems like this, it is generally assumed that the population is so big that your observations are independent.  If something else was intended then, yes.  The population size matters.

Comment: @lulu ok, so then $0.9^n=0.2\to n=15.275531...$. But you can't select $15.275531$ people, but we do have $0.9^{15}=0.20589...$, but this is not equal to $0.2$?

Comment: So, do the usual integer programming thing.  Check $15$, check $16$.  In this case, it's a monotone function, so the answer is clearly $16$.

Comment: You should get used to being a bit flexible in these problems.  Yes, they should have clarified about the population, yes they should have said *at least* $80\%$, but then the $10\%$ is obviously a made up number so we're just talking about estimations here.

Comment: Your (subtle) question about independence of events is a good one.  Suppose that you change the question so that there are $~30~$ people in a room, and you are given that $~10\%~$ of them are left handed.  Then (for example), the probability that two random people are both right handed becomes $~\dfrac{27}{30} \times \dfrac{26}{29},~$ rather than $~\left(\dfrac{27}{30}\right)^2.$